# Android OpenGL ES - Very Weird Pixel Color from glReadPixels - Switched Image?

Tags: android, graphics, opengl-es, shader

I am trying to return the pixel color by TouchEvents in OpenGL ES on Android. I created 2 Triangles as a rectangle. So I put the shown Image on it. The black area is not a part of the Triangles.

[image]

If I click on the black area, it always gives me the correct number 0 0 0 -1 (black). If i click on the white area it also gives me always the correct number -1 -1 -1 -1 (white). But when I click on the green rectangle, it gives me 0 0 0 -1 (black). After that I am clicking on the black rectangle next to him and it gives me the color of the neighbor(green).

**The image switched in the "background", but I don't know how this is possible**

Used this Tut: http://androidblog.reindustries.com/a-real-open-gl-es-2-0-2d-tutorial-part-1/

My Code for Color Picking:

```
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {

if (clicked) {
            gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
            gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_FOG);
            gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_BLEND);

            ByteBuffer ss = ByteBuffer.allocate(4);
            ss.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
            gl.glFlush();
            gl.glReadPixels(touchXint, touchYint, 1, 1, GLES20.GL_RGBA, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, ss);

            byte b[] = new byte[4];
            ss.get(b);
            String key = "" + b[0] + " " + b[1] + " " + b[2] + " " + b[3];
            Log.d("Color: ", key);
            clicked = false;
            ss.rewind();

            gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
            gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_FOG);
            gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_BLEND);


        }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to have a problem with coordinate systems. In many window/UI systems, including Android, the coordinates you receive as part of events are relative to the top/left corner of the window.

On the other hand, the window coordinate system used by OpenGL for specifying the pixel rectangle for `glReadPixels()` has its origin in the bottom/left corner. You can see that in the [documentation](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man3/xhtml/glReadPixels.xml), where `x` and `y` are described by:

> Specify the window coordinates of the first pixel that is read from the frame buffer. This location is the lower left corner of a rectangular block of pixels.

To accommodate for these different coordinate systems, you have to invert the y-coordinate of your touch input before passing it to `glReadPixels()`. Instead of `touchYint`, use `windowHeight - 1 - touchYint`.

Answer (score 1):

It's not the real answer, why your problem is occuring, but it seems like your X coordinate is inverted. I mean, the horizontal 0 is swapped with screenWidth. Just to confirm it you can try something like

```
gl.glReadPixels(screenWidth - touchXint, touchYint, 1, 1, GLES20.GL_RGBA, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, ss);
```

If it works, then you should search the problem in obtaining you touchXint coordinate.

Edit:

In this case the screen is oriented horizontally, so the horizontal axis is Y. The direction of Y axis in OpenGL coordinate system and Android coordinate system is inverted. Therefore, to get the right Y coordinate for the glReadPixels call, the following transform needs to be applied: y = (screenHeight-touchYint).

Comment: How are you getting touchXint ? Are you sure that you know what is your screen coordinate system? It doesn't need to be the same as OpenGL screen space.

Comment: touchXInt os from MotionEvent. Yea I guess the coordinate system from MotionEvent and OpenGL is not the same. I will check this.

Comment: The next question is: How can I invert the Y-Axis of OpenGL or MotionEvent?

Comment: The thing is: OpenGL uses a coordinate system with 0,0 in the center and y pointing upwards. Android uses 0,0 in top-left corner. So you need a transform like this: X=touchX - (screenWidth/2); Y= -touchY+(screenHeight/2). Use X,Y in glReadPixels call and you should be fine

Comment: The origin of the coordinates used for `glReadPixels()` is in the bottom-left corner of the window, not the center. You might be thinking of normalized device coordinates (NDC), where the origin is in the center. But the input for `glReadPixels()` is in a different coordinate system.

Comment: Yes, Reto Korandi is right about the coordina system. I was thinking about the NDC.

Comment: @RetoKoradi yes you was right! `y = (screenHeight-touchYint)`
the smartphone was horizontal. so @Elvithari was right, too

Comment: Sure, will do. I was actually responding to @Elvithari's comment. I didn't realize that I was answering the original question.

Comment: @csnewb: Ok, great. I've edited the answer so it's now the real answer to your question. Glad you've sorted it out.